# terminate keyboard input C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a `client-to-server` project in C++ and I'm having hard times finding a solution for the following scenario:

Thread no' 1 (responsible for sending messages)-

```cpp
    while(!shouldTerminate){ 
    // some code here
    cin.getLine
    // more code here
    }
```

`shouldTerminate` is boolean shared between this thread and Thread no' 2 (responsible for receiving messages) that gets `true` value when Thread no' 2 gets a message to acknowledge about logout.

I'm trying to figure out how to terminate `cin` and make it break out of the loop so my Client will shut down.

Any wise words? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can simply [set `std::cin`'s `fail()`bit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate).

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. You will have to resort to operating system-specific resources to implement this, and operating system-specific means to handle terminal input. Neither `std::cin`, nor any other C++ library class, is thread safe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: "Neither `std::cin`, nor any other C++ library class, is thread safe." That's not even true for `std::cin`: see [iostream.objects.overview] paragraph 7. Admittedly, that only applies to bytes written or read and is due to the C library guarantees. ... and the C++ library does contain some classes which are thread safe, notably those meant to deal with concurrency like `std::mutex` or `std::atomic<T>`.

Comment: Maybe async I/O with a select() statement would help?